# monotonically_increasing_id function behaviour explanation in Spark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark

I have been using `monotonically_increasing_id()` for a long time and I just discovered a weird behaviour, I need explanations please.

So I have a df with 20 000 lines.

I added an Id column:

`val df2 = df.withColumn("Id", monotonically_increasing_id().cast("int"))`

And surprise, I didnt get monotonically increasing ids, I found Id=1 on 5 different rows, Id=2 on 2 rows ....

So I thought maybe it was because of Spark distributing my dataframe, to be sure I did the following:

`val df2 = df.coalesce(1).withColumn("Id", monotonically_increasing_id().cast("int"))`

And the weird behaviour disappeared.

Are my thoughts right ? Doesn't `monotonically_increasing_id()` manage dataframes repartitions automatically ?

Why didn't I encounter this behaviour previously, I always worked with much bigger dataframes and never did I have this error.

Thanks

Comment: Add but why would you need to convert?

Comment: Because I am inserting the df into an sql table woth integer as id column type

Comment: odd story but hard to explain.

Answer (score -1):

This may have to do with integer overflow as monotonically_increasing_id returns a long datatype.